# I want my tablet's hardware back button (Android) to close my website's lightbox

Tags: jquery

I have this lightbox (Colorbox) that works perfect, but there's one problem.

If I press the hardware back button on my tablet, I want the lightbox to exit. Instead of closing the lightbox, the hardware back button exits the entire website and goes back in history--that's not what the user would expect.

So I'd like the back button to close my lightbox 
`$.colorbox.close();` without going back in history. I only want to modify the back button behavior when my lightbox is open.

If it makes any difference, the lightbox closes with the escape key.

Just to be clear, I'm not building an Android application. It's a website with images that open in a jQuery lightbox. If I need "jQuery Mobile" for your solution, please specify.

Here's the link to the lightbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Thanks to Radek Pech's solution, it's working and I didn't need jQuery Mobile either. You can try out the lightbox here if you're curious http://ProductInterest.com just tap one of the thumbnails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the lightbox, you must add new history state.

Then you can watch for popstate event end close the lightbox.

```
history.pushState(null, "Colorbox", '#colorbox');

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    $.colorbox.close();
};
```

Comment: FYI, doing it this way will cause unexpected results if you start using pushState/popstate for more than one thing.

Comment: Works like a charm, you are brilliant! Just tested on my Galaxy Tab 4. FWIW this works without using jQuery Mobile. And @NathanMacInnes good to know. But I just need this for the lightbox, for now at least.

Comment: Yes, this is only a very simple version. Correctly you should watch for history.state and do an appropriate action.

Comment: You should preserve the URL with `window.location.pathname + window.location.search` before the hash. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38249245/2418655

Answer (score 0):

To extend upon the answer by Radek Pech:

We need to tweak those a bit to work better with Colorbox. Firstly, we need to preserve the URI and querystrings. Secondly, we need to have not only a `$.colorbox.close();` function within the `onLoad`, but also a `history.replaceState` in the `onClosed` too so that a normal close (esc, overlay click, etc) works the URL as desired. We can also tweak the name of the state to include document.title.

So this is how those colorbox init states would look with these:

```
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    onLoad: function() {
        history.pushState(null, document.title + ' [colorbox-active]', window.location.pathname + window.location.search + '#colorbox-active');
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            $.colorbox.close();
        };
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        history.replaceState(null, document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    }
});
```